# how to open javascript popup and add a variable to a href using document.write?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my popup link

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popup('example.com/info?1234', 'PopupWindowCenter')">LINK</a>
```

I need add a variable to the popup link

```
var code01=1234;

document.write("<a href=onclick='popup(example.com/info/+code01+)', 'PopupWindowCenter')">LINK</a>")
```

sorry for any problem or anything.
thanks for all

Comment: so basically you want to dynamically change the param after **info?**

Comment: why is your document.write string partially out ???

Comment: you can end string by " & then add your dynamic variable using + and again start and again continue your string by " .....let me show you an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template literal

```html
<script>
function popup(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b)
}
</script>
<script>
var code01 = 1234;

document.write(`<a href="#" onclick="popup('example.com/info/${code01}', 'PopupWindowCenter')">LINK</a>`)
</script>
```

Comment: thax
in you href="#" a used the "javascript:void(0);" and it work for me. 
thax again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support older versions of JS without template literals, try

```
document.write("<a href=onclick='popup(example.com/info/"+code01+")', 'PopupWindowCenter')">LINK</a>")
```